# IF 'AND-OR' ISFILTERED combination in DAX giving problems

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

Below is the sample dataset

[image]

The data has two slicers ( date and  category ) shown below

[image]

I am writing a DAX Statement to multiply the **sum(values) * 10** only if the date range is in the current year **2023.**

The **StartYear** gives the start of the current year, **firstD** gives the lowest date from the date slicer.

```
Formula = 
var new = sum(Test[Value]) * 10
var startyear = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1) 
var firstD = CALCULATE( MIN( Test[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Test[Date]) )
return if( ISFILTERED(Test[Categories]) && firstD >= startyear, new, 0 )
```

Now when I filter dates to 2023, the total value should be 2300 but it shows as 0

[image]

However the DAX works when I select A or B

[image]

If we remove the ISFILTERED function then, it gives wrong value, the expected value is 0 because the start date is in 2022, but it shows 650

let me know if that is the right syntax

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using a separate calendar table to handle this, which you need!

In your very last example you have set your slicer to some time late 2022, but the minimum value of `'Test'[Date]` for your selected category is in year 2023. Hint: set the slicer to e.g. 2022-12-14, this will include a 2022-date for Category A in your data.

Your measure behaves exactly how it is supposed to, in other words!

To fix this, you need to do the following:

1. Create a calendar table in your model, this should contain contiguous dates, which is necessary for the filtering method you want
2. Establish a relationship between the calendar table and existing `Test` table.
3. Use the date column from your new calendar table in your slicer and as date reference in your measure

Exactly how to create a calendar table is thoroughly documented on Google, I recommend you search and find an article or video you understand for implementing this.

Lastly: Your use of `ISFILTERED` in this measure seems strange, since you mention nowhere the requirement of only showing a number if the column you are testing filtering on is filtered, if that makes sense.. :-) The way you describe your calculation, you **only** need to check whether the selected date range starts in current year.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have fixed this, Added a date dimension table, and selected the Start Date from there and Min Date from the dataset. Works fine now. Also removed isfiltered(), seems like it works without that function